# Dynamic solution for calling a function in R

Tags: r, portfolio, r-portfolioanalytics

i am trying to implement a "dynamic" solution in R.
In the first place, i did run a portfolio optimization for 4 different strategies: MV, CVaR, Entropy Pooling and naive.

As next step, i want to calculate some performance measurements such as the HHI.

My Question is now: How can i simplify my Code? As previously mentioned, i got 4 different strategies for which i retrieved 4 different data frames with the corresponding optimized weights. There is certainly a solution for simplifying this.

```
# call function
hhi_MV <- comp_HHI(weights_MV)
hhi_CVAR <- comp_HHI(weights_CVAR)
hhi_EP <- comp_HHI(weights_EP)
hhi_naive <- comp_HHI(weights_naive)
```

The first part i.e. via

```
portfolios <- list("MV", "CVAR", "EP", "naive")
paste0("hhi_", i (from portfolios list), sep="")
```

The second part "comp_HHI" is a function, to which i hand over the corresponding weights data frame.

Another example:

```
#### Compute Cumulative Return (can take a while) #####
perf_MV <- comp_perf(r = returns, w = weights_MV, fund = 100, freq = "months")
perf_CVAR <- comp_perf(r = returns, w = weights_CVAR, fund = 100, freq = "months")
perf_EP <- comp_perf(r = returns, w = weights_EP, fund = 100, freq = "months")
perf_naive <- comp_perf(r = returns, w = weights_naive, fund = 100, freq = "months")
```

With the previously presented code, i compute the performance of the respective portfolio (comp_perf --> function) with a rebalancing frequency and a starting fund for computing the final wealth. I would like to implement the code dynamically - put simply: preferably a one-liner.

```
perf_* <- comp_perf(r = returns, w = weights_*, fund = 100, freq = "months")
```

As stated in the line above, i would apply the code as presented with the * symbol dynamically. In other word, i.e. the symbol with a loop over the different portfolio types.

My last question is regarding the following Code:

```
# First compute returns from cumulative returns
return_MV <- monthlyReturn(xts(perf_MV$CumReturn[ ,-1], 
                               order.by = perf_MV$CumReturn[ ,1]))
return_CVAR <- monthlyReturn(xts(perf_CVAR$CumReturn[ ,-1], 
                               order.by = perf_CVAR$CumReturn[ ,1]))
return_EP <- monthlyReturn(xts(perf_EP$CumReturn[ ,-1], 
                               order.by = perf_EP$CumReturn[ ,1]))
return_naive <- monthlyReturn(xts(perf_naive$CumReturn[ ,-1], 
                                  order.by = perf_naive$CumReturn[ ,1]))
```

Is there also a way to implement it dynamically?

Thx in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear how you are generating your weights objects, but it would be much easier to combine the related data in a list. For example

```
weights <- list(MV=weights_MV, CVAR=weights_CVAR, EP=weights_EP, naive=weights_naive)
```

Then you can just apply a function over the list

```
hh <- lapply(weights, comp_HHI)
```

You can get the values out of the list with `hh$MV` or `hh[["MV"]]`

And with your second example you would do

```
perf <- lapply(weights, function(x) comp_perf(r = returns, w = x, 
    fund = 100, freq = "months"))
```

It's a good idea to avoid variable names that have data stored in them. If you have related values that you wish to perform the same operation in, they should be in a list. R makes it very easy to work with list. Trying to dynamically create variables names is more messy and error prone and just makes everything downstream more difficult to work with as well.

Comment: Or create the list with `weights <- mget(ls(pattern = "weights_.*"))`

Comment: Thx @MrFlick, i got u! But is there an alternative beside the solution with the list? So that i receive 4 separate solutions for every single portfolio type. Put simply, 4 data.fames separately?

Comment: i did edit the initial post, pls see at the end for another example.

Comment: last question: see above!